# Not blocking with cin in a while loop

Tags: c++, arduino

Im rather new at full c++ coming from arduino.  My project is a data collection system that runs in a while loop.  At the end of each loop id like to check if a quit command has been entered from the terminal.  The only means I know to get info from the terminal is cin >> but it blocks the program.

Is there a way to just check if theres anything in the buffer, and then if there is read a byte?  Similar to arduino's Serial.available() and Serial.read() functions

Comment: Try this:
https://medium.com/manash-en-blog/serial-communication-with-an-arduino-using-c-on-windows-d08710186498

Comment: You could [*peek*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) for the next character. Or use some OS-specific way to poll standard input to see if there might be data available.

Comment: I believe you're going to need platform specific stuff. In standard C++ you only have I/O streams, and most systems block if you attempt to read from the console when there aren't any input.

Comment: @Strider That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Or [std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::readsome](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe `peek` still blocks if there's no input.

Comment: @BessieTheCow sorry i have that understand that so "^^

Comment: You could try `readsome` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome, but it is not guaranteed to work on every platform.

Comment: I guess ive phrased this wrong.  Im on raspberry pi zero w running headless.  I would be happy to be able to hit crtl+c and change the variable driving the loop.  Ive read something about sigaction but haven't figured it out yet.  Am I heading down the right path?

Comment: You can use `sigwaitinfo` with zero timeout to check for a pending signal (^C sends `SIGINT` IIRC). It has to be blocked (using `sigprocmask` or `pthread_sigmask`) for that to work (otherwise it will terminate the program unless you setup a handler, but that requires way more care).

Comment: Can you clarify which environment you are using? It sounds like you are coming to this problem from a background with Arduinos but are now using something else. Is that correct? Please make this clearer to get better answers.